# Vertical text align on side menu xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have been trying to centralize the text- "Hello Janine Alexander" on this side menu but to no avail. I have tried YAlign="Center" and also VerticalTextAlignment="Center" but neither have moved it even an inch down. Any help will be appreciated. I do think its in the navigation bar resulting in it not moving vertically down.How do i fix this

[image]

Here is the complete xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="loyaltyworx1.Profile">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="Menu"
                 BackgroundColor="#2196F3">

            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                <Label x:Name="lblMessage" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" />

                <!-- 
             This StackLayout you can use for other
             data that you want to have in your menu drawer
        -->
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#2196F3"
                     HeightRequest="150">

                    <Label Text=""
                 FontSize="20"
                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 TextColor="White"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <ListView x:Name="navigationDrawerList"
                  RowHeight="60"
                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                  BackgroundColor="White"
                  ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>

                                <!-- Main design for our menu items -->
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Padding="20,10,0,10"
                             Spacing="20">

                                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                         WidthRequest="40"
                         HeightRequest="40"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                                           />

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                         FontSize="Medium"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         TextColor="#343f42"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>

        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>

        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're adding it to the Navigation bar of the MasterDetailPage. If so, you're not going to be able to move it down. What I did on my app was to remove the navigationbar in the MasterDetailPage and in the content page I added the label with binding to add the name of the logged in user.

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <local:MasterPage x:Name ="masterPage"/>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

</MasterDetailPage>
```

MasterPage.xaml

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="MyApp.MasterPage"
                 Padding="0,10,0,0"
                 Icon="hamburger.png"
                 Title="Menu">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,10,0,0">
                    <Label Text="&#xf2be;" FontSize="40" FontFamily="FontAwesome" />
                    <Label x:Name="Username" Text="{Binding UserFullName}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
.....
```

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH5dy.png)

If that's not the issue please add the code that is wrapping the label to get a better idea of what could be happening.

Comment: Thanks @11011, I have added the complete xaml, what do i need to change there to get it working? Thanks

Comment: @Unicorn_Girl I copied your code and added it to project. Everything worked as expected and the menu displayed correctly. I'm not sure why it's not showing correctly on your end. Did you add in any customized them in the Android project (styles.xml) or do you some backed code changing the height of the menu so it extends behind the action bar?

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work, I overlooked the "VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" and was using  "Center" instead. Thanks for your help! :)